# VLOOKUP by Combining 2 Columns to Form a Unique Key

Tags: vba, excel

For the following table,

[image: excel table]

I want to look up the value in col C. Since the values in col A and col B are not unique, VLOOKUP fails. For example, VLOOKUP(1,table,3) returns 5 and never 1.

However, the *combinations* of cols A & B are unique. For example, 1blah = 5, while 1foo = 1.

How can I use the combination of cols A & B as a unique key to return the corresponding value in col C?

I'm not sure if this should be implemented with worksheet functions or a custom VBA function. I tried using CONCATENATE to generate the unique key, but this did not work because this results in combinations of numbers and strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

```
=INDEX($C$1:$C$7,MATCH("1foo",$A$1:$A$7 & $B$1:$B$7,0))
```

just select in example `D1`, enter formula in formula bar and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it

Comment: I do not know ahead of time what the data in col A and B will be. Would your solution still work?

Comment: It will work. i.e you have `1` in `F1` and `foo` in `F2` then you can write `=INDEX(C1:C7,MATCH(F1 & F2,$A$1:$A$7 & $B$1:$B$;0))`

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do it is by concatenating the values separated by a pipe character (|). See the formula in the screenshot below.

[image: =A1&"|"&B1]

Then you can vlookup using the concatenated key.

```
=VLOOKUP("1|foo",$C$1:$D$7,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me. The instructions for VLOOKUP state: "By default, the table must be sorted in an ascending order." Mine is not, and cannot, since I don't know ahead of time what the data will be (it is input by the user). I thus get the last instance regardless of the unique key.

Comment: That only applies if you pass in true as the last argument to vlookup. we're using false here.

Comment: I get #N/A if I include the FALSE, and the last instance if I don't.

Comment: In vlookup, TRUE means to do a binary search and return the closest match if not found. (If the data is not sorted, it will return a meaningless value from the list). FALSE means do a linear search and return #N/A if the value is not found. Something is off between how you're typing the key in the formula and how you're formatting the keys in the list. I'd look carefully for extra spaces, etc.

Comment: Yeah, something's fishy. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP if your lookup value is a concatenation of your two or more key fields (A2&B2).  Then, add a first sorted column in your LUT sheet with the array that is the concatenation of the same key fields.  Viola.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the accepted answer, it is also possible to use column and table names in this type of formula if you are using named tables, which makes the whole thing somewhat easier to read:

[image: Screenshot of two Excel tables, one corresponding to the original example, and one showing how to use a lookup from a table column.]

Assuming the first table from the example is called *MyTable*, with columns named "First", "Second", "Third", you can look up its contents based on a compound key from the first and second columns of another table (named "One" and "Two") with a formula like this in column "Three":

```
=INDEX(MyTable[Third], MATCH([@One]&[@Two], MyTable[First]&MyTable[Second], 0))
```

Using "0" for the last parameter of MATCH allows *MyTable* to be unsorted and returns *#NV* if no match is found.

It is usually not necessary to remember the exact syntax, as Excel will auto-complete the column and table names if you highlight the corresponding cells in your worksheet while writing the formula.