# Unique ID generation in MS-Excel

Tags: database, excel

I need to create an unique ID in an excel sheet with the combination of values from other columns. [image]

The ID should be like **IP-(First three letters of column B)-(Random 4 digit number)-(First three letters of column D)**

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21392397/5513005) may help you.

Comment: @YashKaranke For combining values from two different columns..this will work. But I need to take first three characters from the column. How to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this. It gives the ID no. as in your screen shot.

```
="IP"&"_"&LEFT(UPPER(B2),3)&"_"&TEXT(ROW()-1,"0000")&"_"&LEFT(UPPER(D2),3)
```

Comment: Thank You so Much. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Is there any possibility to generate that 4 digit number randomly. i.e., not like the sequence order

Comment: There is a way. But there is a possibility that it may not be unique. You can replace row()-1 with randbetween(1000,9999). Also the random number will keep on changing. You will have to paste them as values after entering the formula

Comment: Thank for your immediate solution. It will help me a lot