# INDEX to combine two columns, where one column spans on multiple rows

Tags: excel, google-sheets

My `INDEX` formula, based on [this answer to VLOOKUP by Combining 2 Columns to Form a Unique Key question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21392397/6439240) does not work in a situation, where one of the `MATCH`'es `lookup_range` arguments spans on multiple rows:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$5, MATCH($A$3 & $B$3, $A$3:$A$5 & $B$3:$B$5, 0))
                                     ^       ^
                                     |       |
                                     +---+---+
                                         |
                      lookup_range column spans multiple rows
```

Usage:

```
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| \ |   A  |   B   |       C       |        D        |        E       |
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1 |                               CARS                              |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | Make | Model | Current price | Production Year | Original price |
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3 | Audi | A1    | 40000         | 2013            | =MY_FORMULA    |
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4 | Audi | A2    | 50000         | 2010            | =MY_FORMULA    |
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 5 | Audi | A3    | 60000         | 2014            | =MY_FORMULA    |
+---+------+-------+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

It **does work** for this table:

```
+---+------+-------+-------+
| \ |   A  |   B   |   C   |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 1 |        Prices        |
+---+----------------------+
| 2 | Make | Model | Price |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 3 | Audi | A1    | 50000 |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 4 | Audi | A2    | 60000 |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 5 | Audi | A3    | 70000 |
+---+------+-------+-------+
```

It **does not work** for this table (and I want it to):

```
+---+------+-------+-------+
| \ |   A  |   B   |   C   |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 1 |        Prices        |
+---+----------------------+
| 2 | Make | Model | Price |
+---+------+-------+-------+
| 3 | Audi | A1    | 50000 |
+---+      +-------+-------+
| 4 |      | A2    | 60000 |
+---+      +-------+-------+
| 5 |      | A3    | 70000 |
+---+------+-------+-------+
```

It is obvious to span the **AUDI** value on multiple rows to avoid redundancy and typos. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are they merged cells ? Otherwise you can use table fill down to populate the missing values.

Comment: Yes, those are merged cells @QHarr

Comment: Have you considered a helper column containing A3&B3 etc? for the match to work with?

Comment: I tried the formula and it works with a few tweaks in every case I could think of. Could you elaborate a little more what you're trying to do? Are the small tables part of the big table and when you use the last table the formula doesn't work because Audi in row 4 and row 5 is missing? Maybe there is some more rows of data i.e. there are other cars.

Comment: Yes, it is just an overview of a much bigger table and yes, the last formula doesn't work because Audi in rows 4 and 5 is missing. I cannot think of a better explanation of the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this in Google Sheets with a vlookup as follows:-

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(E3&F3,{vlookup(row(A$3:A$10),{if(A$3:A$10<>"",row(A$3:A$10)),A$3:B$10},2)&B$3:B$10,C$3:C$10},2,false))
```

The inner vlookup finds the last row containing a car make with row number less than or equal to the current row. The outer vlookup can be an index match if you prefer, and you can expand the ranges to the last row by putting A$3:A etc.

[image]

---

For completeness, in Excel you have to coax the Index function into giving you an array that you can work on [see this](https://exceljet.net/formula/return-array-with-index-function)

```
=INDEX(C$3:C$10,MATCH(E3&F3,INDEX(A$3:A$10,N(IF({1},MATCH(ROW(A$3:A$10),IF(A$3:A$10<>"",ROW(A$3:A$10))))))&B$3:B$10,0))
```

entered as an array formula.